# UITableView don't reload data

Tags: swift, uitableview, tableview, reloaddata

I got an array that populates a tableview, it works fine when I run the app.

I created a popover with a PickerView to choose one option to sort the TableView data.

I get the user choise in the popover, pass it to the main ViewController, sorted the data and called `tableview.reloadData()` but nothing happens.

I printed the array after the sort and the array is sorted but I can't saw the changes.

But if I go to other ViewController and came back the data is changed.

Why the changes are not showing when I call the `tableview.reloadData()`.

Here's the code:

```
var dataModel = DataModel()
var ordenacao = String()

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

    dataModel.loadData()
    tableView.reloadData()
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    ordenadados(ordem: ordenacao)
    tableView.reloadData()
}

 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell: UITableViewCell! = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cellIdentifier")       
    cell.textLabel?.text = dataModel.notas[indexPath.row].titulo
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = dataModel.notas[indexPath.row].datafinal

    print("Ordena Tableview")

    for nota in dataModel.notas {
        print (nota.titulo ?? "")
    }

    return cell
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return dataModel.notas.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    dataModel.notas.remove(at: indexPath.row)

    self.tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath as IndexPath], with: UITableViewRowAnimation.fade)
    dataModel.saveData()
}
```

EDIT:

```
func ordenadados(ordem: String){

    dataModel.loadData()

    if(ordenacao == "Titulo Asc."){
        print("Titulo Asc")
        dataModel.notas.sort { $0.titulo! < $1.titulo! }
    }else if(ordenacao == "Titulo Desc."){
        print("Titulo Desc.")
        dataModel.notas.sort { $0.titulo! > $1.titulo! }
    }

    dataModel.saveData()

    for nota in dataModel.notas {

        print (nota.titulo ?? "")

    }
    dataModel.loadData()
    tableView.reloadData()

}
```

In the output the array was sorted but in the TableView nothing changed.
[image]

Save and Load Data methods:

```
 //save data
func saveData() {
    let data = NSMutableData()
    let archiver = NSKeyedArchiver(forWritingWith: data)
    archiver.encode(notas, forKey: "teste")
    archiver.finishEncoding()
    data.write(toFile: dataFilePath(), atomically: true)
}

//read data
func loadData() {
    let path = self.dataFilePath()
    let defaultManager = FileManager()
    if defaultManager.fileExists(atPath: path) {
        let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)
        let data = try! Data(contentsOf: url)
        let unarchiver = NSKeyedUnarchiver(forReadingWith: data)
        notas = unarchiver.decodeObject(forKey: "teste") as! Array
        unarchiver.finishDecoding()
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try clearing out your data model, reload the table, then apply the sorted data model, then reloading the table?

Comment: Your view ordering is based on the order of dataModel.notas. When you are sorting you are sorting dados.notas. I cannot see where dataModel.notas is set to this sorted value after the sort. What do dados.saveData() and dados.loadData() do?

Comment: @RadagasttheBrown how?

Comment: Can you try calling dataModel.loadData() before tableView.reloadData() in your ordenadados function

Comment: @Pruthvikar that is already done after the dataModel.saveData(). I already changed "dados" for "dataModel"

Comment: Can you add an edit to the bottom of your answer with your current code?

Comment: done... if you look at the image the array is sorted (see the print in the output) but tableview don't update